# Add second marker on google maps activity in android on user input

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a google maps activity with a map an edittext and a button.

[The screenshot of the activity that I have ready at the moment.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxrl3.png)

Whenever this activity is opened a marker is added to the map.

What I want further in this is that whenever the user inputs an address in that edittext and clicks the button, then another marker is added on the same map without erasing the previous marker and a polyline is created in the map joining the two markers.

I have tried adding the second marker but the app just crashes and I am not able to do that. It would be a great help if you guys can help me in adding the second marker.

Here is the activity code :

```
    public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private EditText findRouteEdittext;
    private Button findRouteButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
        List<Address> addressList;
        LatLng coord = null;

        String completeAddress = intent.getStringExtra("completeAddress");

        try {
            addressList = coder.getFromLocationName(completeAddress, 5);
            if (addressList != null) {

                Address location = addressList.get(0);

                coord = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        mMap = googleMap;

        MarkerOptions mMarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        mMarkerOptions.position(coord);
        mMarkerOptions.title(completeAddress);
        mMap.addMarker(mMarkerOptions).showInfoWindow();
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(coord));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coord, 14.0f));
    }
}
```

---

EDIT 1

---

I finally got the answer myself, on where to add, it was basically a minor error but just so other people know where to add I will update the answer here :

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

        private GoogleMap mMap;
        private EditText findRouteEdittext;
        private Button findRouteButton;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
            // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

          findRouteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                searchString = findRouteEdittext.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim();


                if (searchString.equals("")){
//                    findRouteEditTextInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
//                    findRouteEditTextInputLayout.setError("Enter a location or City!");
                    //use snackbar to show something.

                }
                else{

                    coder2 = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this);
                    coord2 = null;

                    try {
                        addressList2 = coder2.getFromLocationName(searchString, 5);
                        if (addressList2 != null) {

                            Address location = addressList2.get(0);

                            coord2 = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                        }

                    } catch (Exception ex) {

                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    if (coord2!=null && coord!=null) {
                        mMap.clear();
                        mMarkerOptions2 = new MarkerOptions();
                        mMarkerOptions2.position(coord2);
                        mMarkerOptions2.title(searchString); //this is the address of the new string entered by the user
                        mMap.addMarker(mMarkerOptions2).showInfoWindow();

                        mMarkerOptions3 = new MarkerOptions();
                        mMarkerOptions3.position(coord);
                        mMarkerOptions3.title(completeAddress); //this is the address of the original string received from intent
                        mMap.addMarker(mMarkerOptions3).showInfoWindow();
                    }
               }

        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
            List<Address> addressList;
            LatLng coord = null;

            String completeAddress = intent.getStringExtra("completeAddress");

            try {
                addressList = coder.getFromLocationName(completeAddress, 5);
                if (addressList != null) {

                    Address location = addressList.get(0);

                    coord = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {

                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            mMap = googleMap;

            MarkerOptions mMarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            mMarkerOptions.position(coord);
            mMarkerOptions.title(completeAddress);
            mMap.addMarker(mMarkerOptions).showInfoWindow();
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(coord));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coord, 14.0f));
        }
    }
```

Comment: you didn't mention onclick listener for  findRouteButton.

Comment: i deleted all the code that wasnt working out for me, if you want I can rewrite what I did and show it to you. but it just didnt work so I posted what is working perfectly for me and deleted all that wasnt.

Answer (score 0):

If you already got Location object then use below code to add new marker in to map.

```
latitude = location.getLatitude();
longitude = location.getLongitude();
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
```

place this code in side add button on click listener.

Comment: I figured it out already bro, had a minor error, but I wasnt asking "how to" I was asking "where to" add the code since I was having trouble while adding on either of them but I guess it was due to that error only. 

Anyways thanks for your time.

Comment: Glad to help you.